# Moving files asynchronously in powershell

Tags: powershell, asynchronous, powershell-3.0

I have the following problem: I am writing a loop that checks if some files appeared in a folder and if so then moves those files to another folder.

The script works nicely now, here is its code:

```
$BasePath = "C:\From"
$TargetPath = "C:\To"
$files = Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path "$($BasePath)\$($Filename)" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $subdirectorypath = split-path $file.FullName.Replace($BasePath, "").Trim("\")
    $targetdirectorypath = "$($TargetPath)\$($subdirectorypath)"
    if ((Test-Path $targetdirectorypath) -eq $false)
    {
        Write-Host "Creating directory: $targetdirectorypath"
        md $targetdirectorypath -Force
    }

    Write-Host "Copying file to: $($targetdirectorypath.TrimEnd('\'))\$($File.Name)"
    Move-Item $File.FullName "$($targetdirectorypath.TrimEnd('\'))\$($File.Name)" -Force
}
```

However, as some of those files can be quite big, I would like to move those files asynchronously, in a "fire-and-forget" way. What is the best way to do it with powershell? This script will probably be running forever, so any asynchronous jobs would have to dispose themselves after they are done copying I think.

Thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use a background job:

```
$scriptblock = {
    $BasePath = $args[0]
    $TargetPath = $args[1]
    $files = Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path "$($BasePath)\$($Filename)" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    foreach ($file in $files)
    {
        $subdirectorypath = split-path $file.FullName.Replace($BasePath, "").Trim("\")
        $targetdirectorypath = "$($TargetPath)\$($subdirectorypath)"
        if ((Test-Path $targetdirectorypath) -eq $false)
        {
            Write-Host "Creating directory: $targetdirectorypath"
            md $targetdirectorypath -Force
        }

        Write-Host "Copying file to: $($targetdirectorypath.TrimEnd('\'))\$($File.Name)"
        Move-Item $File.FullName "$($targetdirectorypath.TrimEnd('\'))\$($File.Name)" -Force
    }
}

$arguments = @("C:\From","C:\To")
start-job -scriptblock $scriptblock -ArgumentList $arguments
```

If later you want to see any output from the job you can do the following

```
Get-Job | Receive-Job
```